# Get params from request body, but cannot be used in mybatis annotation join query

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, maven, mybatis

I am using Springboot integrated with maven and Mybatis. I wanna make a join query using the following code. Total I need 3 queries** to achieve the result. Wanna ask **what is the correct way of passing parameters through out queries**?

The first one is my main table which I can get all the hotels name, those **two params** is passed from user but they **will not be used in this query**.

column `classes` in the first query is where I have my many-to-many query

```
@Select("Select * from hotels ")
@Results(value = {
            @Result(column = "id", property = "id", id = true),
            @Result(column = "chiName", property = "chiName"),
            @Result(column = "engName", property = "engName"),
            @Result(column = "{id, startDate, endDate}", property = "classes", many = @Many(select = "getAllClass")),
            @Result(column = "telephone", property = "telephone")
    })
List<Map<String, Hotel>> getAllHotels(@Param("startDate") String startDate, @Param("endDate") String endDate);
```

My second query is as follow, what I try to do is to pass the parameter from first query but it is not succeed.

```
@Select("Select * from classes " +
            "left join hotels on hotels.id = classes.hotelId " +
            "WHERE classes.hotelId = #{hotels.id} "
    )
    @Results({
            @Result(column = "id", property = "id", id = true),
            @Result(column = "hotelId", property = "hotelId"),
            @Result(column = "className", property = "className"),
            @Result(column = "isActivate", property = "isActivate"),
            @Result(column = "totalRoom", property = "totalRoom"),
            @Result(column = "availableRoom", property = "availableRoom"),
            @Result(column = "{id, startDate, endDate}", property = "bookingRecords", many = @Many(select = "getBookingRecords"))
    })
    List<Class> getAllClass();
```

My third query:

```
    @Select("Select * from booking_records " +
            "left join classes on classes.id = booking_records.classId  " +
            "WHERE booking_records.classId = #{classes.id} " +
            "AND " +
            "`date` BETWEEN #{startDate} AND #{endDate}"
    )
    @Results({
            @Result(column = "id", property = "id", id = true),
            @Result(column = "userId", property = "userId"),
            @Result(column = "classId", property = "classId"),
            @Result(column = "date", property = "date"),
            @Result(column = "isActivate", property = "isActivate"),
    })
    List<BookingRecord> getBookingRecords();
```

Comment: Are you OK with using XML mapper? With your current approach, if there are 10 hotels, the second query `getAllClass()` will be executed 10 times. And if each hotel has 3 classes, the total number of queries will be 1 + 10 + 30 = 41. With XML mapper, it may be possible to get the same result with a single query with JOINs. If this is new information to you, see the explanation of 'nested select' and 'nested results' in the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html).

Comment: I will try the XML method since I haven't got any progress in using annotation. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used mybatis xml file to write this. Below is what I had. Please take reference if needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.hotelmanagementsys.hotelmang.dao.SearchMapper">
    <resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="Hotel">
        <id property="id" column="id"/>
        <result property="chiName" column="chiName"/>
        <result property="engName" column="engName"/>
        <result property="telephone" column="telephone"/>

        <collection property="classes" column="id" ofType="Class" javaType="List">
            <result property="id" column="id"/>
            <result property="hotelId" column="hotelId"/>
            <result property="className" column="className"/>
            <result property="isActivate" column="isActivate"/>
            <result property="totalRoom" column="totalRoom"/>
            <result property="availableRoom" column="availableRoom"/>

            <collection property="bookingRecords" column="id" ofType="BookingRecord" javaType="List">
                <result property="id" column="id"/>
                <result property="userId" column="userId"/>
                <result property="classId" column="classId"/>
                <result property="date" column="date"/>
                <result property="isActivate" column="isActivate"/>
            </collection>
        </collection>
    </resultMap>


    <select id="filterHotel" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
        SELECT hotels.*, classes.*, booking_records.* FROM hotels
        LEFT JOIN classes ON (classes.hotelId = hotels.id)
        LEFT JOIN booking_records ON (classes.id = booking_records.classId)
        WHERE booking_records.date BETWEEN #{startDate} AND #{endDate}
    </select>

</mapper>
```